# How does a View know what ViewModel to use in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can someone explain how the View and ViewModel are connected? I can't find anywhere the xaml or the xaml.cs for the View that references the ViewModel, nor anything in the ViewModel.cs file that references the View, yet they are somehow connected, and binding members from the ViewModel to the View work.

Also, in the constructor of each, there is only the InitializeComponent for the View and a basic constructor for the ViewModel (no declaration/definition of the View).

Thanks!

Comment: Since it's unclear whether you're using a third-party MVVM framework, I suspect you'll need to post some code to get an accurate answer.  You *could* connect the view and viewmodel in any of dozens of different ways, and we can't see what code you have in front of you.

Comment: I'd recommend going back to basics - I wrote a series on MVVM that really covers some of the fundimentals, like "what's a view model" and "what's the view" and how they hook together.  It might be worth skimming: http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are various options here.

*Something* has to set the View's `DataContext` to be an instance of the ViewModel.  There are lots of options here:

- This can be done directly in xaml (the View just instances the ViewModel directly).
- This can be done in the View's constructor (`this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();`)
- This can be handled via a `DataTemplate`
- A "coordinating" class can wire these together (ie: a separate "presenter" class can construct both and set the `DataContext` appropriately)

The most common are to either have the View define the VM in the xaml (View-first), or to have everything based from a ViewModel-centric point of view, and have WPF automatically create the View based on the bound VM (ViewModel-first).

The former approach is what's used by a lot of toolkits, such as [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).  The latter approach is what I used in my [MVVM blog series](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/), and used by some other toolkits.

Comment: +1. This "coordinating" class is usually called `Controller` (MVC-pattern) or `Presenter` (MVP-pattern) where the presenter acts as controller and as view-model at the same time. Going towards MVP would mean that the `ViewModel` would open the view.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes unless you use data templates - that way the VM does need to open views.

Comment: @DannyVarod If you're using data templates, WPF effectively becomes the "Presenter" in MVP terms coordinating this for you.

Comment: True, however, it becomes a **generic** Presenter based on Reflection.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks for that! I found where it was, it was embedded somewhere that called something that called something that set the DataContext. (Not something I would have done though...) The ViewModel was created, then defined as the DataContext of the View in an EventHandler. :S

Answer (score 5):

A "clean" way for connecting the views to the view-models would be...

When you create the views, for each view, set its DataSource to its view-model:

E.g.

```
public class App
{
    private void OnAppStart()
    {
        var model = new MainModel();
        var vm = new MainVM();
        var view = new MainWindow();

        vm.Model = model;
        view.DataSource = vm;

        view.Show();
    }
}
```

When the model you are viewing changes, update the VM:

```
public class MainVM
{
    private void OnSelectedModelItemChanged()
    {
        this.SelectedItem = new ItemVM();
        this.SelectedItem.Model = this.SelectedModelItem;
    }
}
```

And use data templates to make view select the correct sub views for each VM.

Answer (score 2):

The view contains an object of the view model class in the xaml.

The InitializeComponent function creates all the controls on the page, sets styles, etc.

Comment: Where would it be? I can't find any text that contains the word "ViewModel" (That's what my view model is called).

Comment: You may want to look at Reed's response. The way I do it is have an object of my viewmodel in the View's xaml.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already shown, there are multiple options.  Of course, whenever you hear of multiple options you have to wonder what are the advantages and disadvantages of each.  Well, it just so turns out that all of them have major disadvantages except one.

The following approach involves no external libraries, no additional housekeeping classes and interfaces, almost no magic, and is very flexible because you can have viewmodels that contain other viewmodels, and you get to instantiate each one of them, so you can pass constructor parameters to them.

### For the viewmodel of the main window:

```
using Wpf = System.Windows;

public partial class TestApp : Wpf.Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup( Wpf.StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnStartup( e );
        MainWindow = new MainView();
        MainWindow.DataContext = new MainViewModel( e.Args );
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

### For all other viewmodels:

This is in MainViewModel.cs:

```
using Collections = System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel SomeViewModel { get; }
    public OtherViewModel OtherViewModel { get; }
    public Collections.IReadOnlyList<string> Arguments { get; }
    
    public MainViewModel( Collections.IReadOnlyList<string> arguments )
    {
        Arguments = arguments;
        SomeViewModel = new SomeViewModel( this );
        OtherViewModel = new OtherViewModel( this );
    }
}
```

This in MainView.xaml:

```
[...]
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:the-namespace-of-my-wpf-stuff"
[...]
    <local:SomeView DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModel}" />
    <local:OtherView DataContext="{Binding OtherViewModel}" />
[...]
```

As you can see, a viewmodel can simply be a member (child) of another viewmodel;  in this case SomeViewModel and OtherViewModel are children of MainViewModel.  Then, in the XAML file of MainView, you can just instantiate each of the child views and specify their `DataContext` by `Binding` to the corresponding child viewmodels.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike, this is exactly the approach I was looking for. I know this is a year old but if you see this, where exactly would you put the two local elements within MainView.xaml?

 <local:SomeView DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModel}" />
 <local:OtherView DataContext="{Binding OtherViewModel}" />

Comment: @dmscs these elements instantiate views, so you just place them there where you want the views to appear.  For example, you can make your main view contain nothing but a `StackPanel`, and make that `StackPanel` contain nothing but these two views, one after the other.